# How to extract data with count grouping by City and usertype in one row

Tags: sql

I need to extract data from a table like this:

```
City | Customer | mail |
```

In the mail field i have two diferent domains (@domain1; @domain2).
I want to count @domain1 and @domain2 grouping by City in one single row by City.

The result shoul look like this:

```
City | total @domain1 | total @domain2
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select city,
       sum(case when email like '%@domain1' then 1 else 0 end) as total_domain1,
       sum(case when email like '%@domain2' then 1 else 0 end) as total_domain2
from t
group by city;
```